# Como traçar uma rota utilizando API do maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou fazendo um aplicativo no Android Studio para um evento e gostaria que:

Ao abrir uma tela específica, o app usaria o gps do celular para adquirir as coordenadas de origem e abriria o app do google maps para criar uma rota com o ponto de destino no local do evento.

desde já, obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seja bem vindo!

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
 // URL para abrir o google maps
final String ulrRoute = "https://maps.google.com?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%s,%s";

// Informe a latitude e longitude do local do evento
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( String.format(Locale.getDefault(),ulrRoute, "-25.429138", "-49.271481") ));

// Informamos que queremos abrir a  Activity MapsActivity do com.google.android.apps.maps
i.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

startActivity(i);
```